# Google Chrome user agent, wrong language

Tags: 10.04, google-chrome, language-support

After some months, my Chrome(now 10.0.648.127 beta; but I tried with the lastest stable too) displayed some popular sites in English, instead of my Chrome & system language, which is Hungarian...

I saw my User-Agent, which shows in **Chrome**: *Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; **en-US**) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.127 Safari/534.16*

But in **Firefox**: *Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; **hu-HU**; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.15*, what is correct...

My question is: How can I change my user-agent(maybe dynamically, by version)? *I tried with google-chrome --user-agent "text", but it failed in the newest versions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Google Chrome menu (looks like a wrench), look under `Options > Under the Hood > "Web Content" > Languages and spell-checker settings...`. There, you should be able to list your preferred languages in priority order.

It seems like this is a bug. It should indeed default to the default locale for your user account.

**Edit**: I just noticed that this method doesn't actually change the [user-agent](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/). (Just the other standard headers that indicate the language -- "Accept-Language" I think?) However, there is a [plug-in](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aafciojnlamllgpkpdkbamkfgbofhgcj) that should allow you to customize this. (though from the comments, it looks like this, too, might have bugs.)

It's too bad web sites are still looking at User-Agent instead of Accept-Language. (It's... [so 1990s](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.4).)